# selecting model training params (and layers)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model

In the code (below, copy/pasted from tensorflow.org "Tensorflow 2 quickstart for beginners", wrt all the many variables, such as:

- number of epochs
- batch_size
- learning_rate
- layer (or combination of layers)
- activation function for each layer
- loss_function
- units (param for Dense layers)
- rate (for Dropout layer)
- etc...

is there some educated procedure, other than "guessing & testing", in order to find the "BEST" combination of params --- or even knowing which combination of params to begin with?

Am I lacking some knowledge (or piece of information) that an "expert" or PhD would provide me, that would give me the ability to select the "BEST" params (the first time)?

I certainly understand that some params the final layer Dense(10) needs to be 10 units to represent the 10 classes... and I understand that 10,000 layers would likely not be good... So I'm not talking about extremes or things like the 10 in the last Dense layer, but rather the other params.

Meaning - as an example - in the code below, lets say I change the the units in the line

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
```

to something else 64 (instead of 32).

wrt to the example below,
Is there a reason why 64 would definitively be better (or worse) than 32?
Is there a reason adding another Dense layer would be better (or worse)?
Is there a definitive reason why training for 6 epochs would be better (or worse) than 5?

I know that if I understood all the calculations that the model was ultimately doing, I would have my answer... which means that since "someone" wrote *that* code, it isn't impossible to have the ability to know this...

It is very frustrating that all the tutorials & sites out there focus on ***how***, instead of ***why***.

(ANY advice/links/resources would be very appreciated)

Many many many thank yous to the experts in advance!

```
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf


def proc(args):
    ( X_train, y_train ), ( X_test, y_test ) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    X_train = X_train / 255.0
    X_test  = X_test / 255.0

    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])

    hist = model.fit(X_train,
                     y_train,
                     batch_size=32,
                     epochs=5,
                     validation_split=0.2,
                     shuffle=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=32)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    proc(args)

``
```

Comment: As you mentioned, there is some crucial knowledge that you lack in the field of machine learning. However, you should probably seek help in other forums, like Cross Validated, for example. Regarding your questions, they are pretty common for people who are new to machine learning, and I am sure that you are going to find your answers in existing questions there. Good luck.

Comment: thank you david... but i am actually asking WHAT EXACTLY are the necessary criteria to become such an "expert" (who has these answers)? these days, as more and more things become globally available & academic degrees more & more unnecessary and obsolete, what exactly are these things I am "lacking"? is it having read XYZ books? is it having spent X number of years creating at least N models? Is it educating myself to a certain level on some areas such as statistics, linear algebra, probability theory and calculus?

Comment: For me it was just working with different problems/datasets. After some time, you get a rough feeling what model size could be good for a certain problem, the rest is model testing / hyperparameter optimization (there is a reason that there are libraries for it like `Optuna`). For starters, there are good starting datasets like e.g.`MNIST` and `CIFAR10` for computer vision, there are many examples working with these datasets. A knowledge about the mathematical basics of what is happening with e.g. cross entropy or BatchNormalization is important too.